# Slurm: variable for max SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID

Tags: cluster-computing, hpc, slurm

I have a simple slurm job file that looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --array=1-1000
#SBATCH -t 60:00
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
python cats.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} 1000
```

That second argument is so my script know the total number of workers in this job.

I'd like to make that 1000 value into a variable though, so I don't need to hardcode the total number of workers. Is there some slurm variable for the maximum array task id in the current job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the environment variable `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_MAX`

Comment: Just to point out: `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_MAX` returns the highest Task ID, which might not be the task count (e.g. when `--array=500-1000`). Better in this case to use `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_COUNT`